# PhoneGap Build Code of wakeuptimer plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Hi I am working on project that use plugin wakeup timer the issue is that I get from **SuccessCallback** (this is the first argument of wakeup) "wakeup unhandled type"
I use the github's plugin https://github.com/wnyc/cordova-plugin-wakeuptimer
my `index.html` Where I must modify JS to make it works?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <!--<meta name="viewport" ... /> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            function init() {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }
            function onDeviceReady() {
                myDevice = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');


                myDevice.innerHTML = window.wakeuptimer.wakeup(function(result) {
                    if (result.type==='wakeup') {
                        alert('wakeup alarm detected--' + result.extra);
                    } else if(result.type==='set'){
                        alert('wakeup alarm set--' + result);
                    } else {
                        alert('wakeup unhandled type (' + result.type + ')');
                    }
                }, function() {
                    alert('Error!');
                }, {alarms : [{type : 'onetime',
                    time : { hour : 15, minute : 00 },
                    extra : { message : 'json containing app-specific information to be posted when alarm triggers' }, 
                    message : 'Alarm has expired!'}]
                    }
);
        }






        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Dane z alarmu</h1>
        <button type="button" id="deviceProperties" onclick="init()">Ustaw alarm</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Version Requirements
>
> This plugin is meant to work with Cordova 3.5.0+.

I use version 1 of PGB so this quote is an answer